# List Permissions for Sharepoint Sites Using GraphAPI

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, sharepoint-permissions, graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve site permissions for SharePoint sites using GraphAPI. I've got the API working and can list sites, subsites, lists, drives, etc. However, when I run /sites/{siteID}/permissions I get the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/permissions",
    "value": []
}
```

It's not showing any of the default or custom site permissions. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am also getting the same result & not able to get the actual permissions

Answer (score 0):

It could be by design, but it looks like the `/sites/{sitesId}/permissions` resource only returs permissions granted to the Azure Apps. It does not return anything related to the good-old classic SharePoint permissions. Example:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "roles": ["read"],
      "grantedToIdentities": [{
        "application": {
          "id": "89ea5c94-7736-4e25-95ad-3fa95f62b66e",
          "displayName": "Contoso Time Manager App"
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "roles": ["write"],
      "grantedToIdentities": [{
        "application": {
          "id": "22f09bb7-dd29-403e-bec2-ab5cde52c2b3",
          "displayName": "Fabrikam Dashboard App"
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Might be unrelated, but overall, Graph API is *extremely* limited when it comes to SharePoint. In terms of SharePoint, you can't do much with Graph API apart from a few basic exceptions. Graph API does not even cover 1% of what is available via REST API, let alone CSOM. As a workaround, perhaps, you could use REST API.